# Regex to remove special characters. Can't get rid of trailing ellipsis

Tags: regex, postgresql

In the context of a postgres query, this -

```
lower(regexp_replace('If...', '[^\w\s]', ''))
```

gives me this -

`'if..'` (quotes mine)

As you can see, only one of the three periods gets trimmed. Can someone tell me what I must add to my regexp to get rid of the other two or any other special characters that might be trailing in this way?

Comment: Please define "special character". And trailing after what exactly?

Comment: In the above case it would be the '...' in the target string but generally I am seeking a regex replacement that will leave only letters, numbers and white space in original string, with nothing like trailing ellipsis hanging on.

Comment: Then my answer is already final.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably looking for the fourth, optional parameter of [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('If...', '[^\w\s]', '', 'g');
```

`g` .. for "globally", i.e. replace every match in the string, not just the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('If, stay real....', '[.]{2,}$', '.', 'g');
```

> {m,}  a sequence of m or more matches of the atom.

More than 2 dot in the string will be replaced with one dot.
further reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html